# Getting the location of a section of a sprite

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

The code below makes a a sprite and assigns anchor point and rotation. The sprite will be rotating around a lot, is there a way to get the location of the bottom right of the sprite. Like, the sprites anchorpoint is (0,1), can i get the location point of anchor (1,1)? that way i can always get the same location of the sprite even though it is rotating?

```
tempsprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"image.png"];
tempsprite.rotation += 90;
tempsprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0,1);
tempsprite.position = tempsprite;
[self addChild:tempsprite];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured it out incase anyone has the same issue I did something like this.

```
int length = 100;
int offset = 50

CGFloat angle = ([self findangle]+offset) * M_PI/180;
CGPoint startpoint1 = startingpoint;
CGPoint endPoint1 =
CGPointMake( startpoint1.x + ( sinf( angle ) * length ), startpoint1.y + ( cosf( angle ) * length ) );


return endPoint1;
```